# Including more than 1 randomly generated item in if statement

Tags: python, random

I'm making a 'slot machine' code and am not able to use more than 1 of the items in the list in an if statement so I can then set separate statements for different item combinations.

Tried using 
if "item1" and "item2" in rand_items:
   or
if "item1" and "item1" in rand_items:
but it only really picks up one of them

```
items = ["diamond", "bomb", "apple"]
rand_items = (random.choices(items, k=3))
            print (rand_items)
            if "bomb" in rand_items:
                print ("Game over.")
                break
            elif "bomb" and "diamond" in rand_items:
                print("You may spin again.")
            elif "diamond" and "diamond" in rand_items:
                print("You won £25.")
```

It should take the two items and if it's a diamond AND bomb, continue or if there's two (more than 1) diamonds 'give' money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that this syntax is incorrect:

```
elif "bomb" and "diamond" in rand_items:
```

The right way to write it is:

```
elif "bomb" in rand_items and "diamond" in rand_items:
```

... Same thing for the other condition. Now, for checking if an item is two times in the list, you can count it:

```
elif rand_items.count("diamond") == 2:
```

Comment: It is not that `if "bomb" and "diamond" in rand_items:` is incorrect, it just doesn't carry out the intended purpose.

Comment: Well, I'd argue that it's incorrect because it's a condition that will always be true ;)

Comment: it seems to be working for that condition but not if I want to have two of the same items; so for the "diamond" and "diamond" one. do you know how i could solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if both `"bomb"` and `"diamond"` are in the choices first then you can check for just bomb. I'd also just suggest using set.issubset`instead of multiple conditions in the if. Also making`items`a`set` would make more sense here as well.

```
from random import choices

items = ["diamond", "bomb", "apple"]
rand_items = set(choices(items, k=3))

if {"bomb", "diamond"} <= rand_items:
    print("You may spin again.")
elif "bomb" in rand_items:
    print ("Game over.")
elif "diamond" in rand_items:
    print("You won £25.")
```

You will need an `else` here as nothing happens if the random choices are all `"apple"`

Comment: As a note, at least for python3.6, `random.choices(items, k=3)` will raise a `TypeError` since `set` does not support an index

Comment: Thanks for that I accidentally made the wrong thing a set. That's what I get for not testing before I edit. Fixed thanks!